# How can I change the whole data of a vue object?

Tags: vue.js

Simply, I just want to change the entire data of a Vue object, like this:

```
vueobj.$data = newdata;
```

but the official document says it's not allowed:

> VM156 vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Avoid replacing instance root $data. Use
>   nested data properties instead.
>
> (found in )

So I tried another way: first destroy the the vueobj by `$destroy()`, then create a new vueobj to bind new data object to the same the UI element, but after that, the UI element still uses the old data. So how could I solve this problem? thanks!

Comment: thank you very much for improving my question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this works for me:

```js
<div id="app">
  {{name}}: {{age}}
</div>

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    name: "Alice",
    age: 30
  },
  methods: {
    refresh(data) {
      Object.assign(this.$data, data); // <--
    }
  }
});

const newData = {
  name: "Bob",
  age: 22
};

app.refresh(newData);
```

Comment: This will break reactivity... so anything you need to be reactive has to be in computed or $set.

Comment: Why would it break reactivity @RayFoss ? `Object.assign` calls setters on the target object (in this case `this.$data`), which is all that vue2 reactivity system uses. 
In other words, using `Object.assign(this.$data, source)` is the same as if you assigned to each individual property in `this.$data` manually.

Comment: Can confirm this does not break reactivity. It is the best answer.

Answer (score 7):

It is tricky, but you could iterate over the data properties and:

- First: remove all `data` properties;
- Second: add each property of the `newdata` object to the `data` object.

Demo below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: 'Alice',
    age: 30
  },
  methods: {
    changeWholeData() {
      let newdata = {name: 'Bob', age: 40};
       // erase all current keys from data
       Object.keys(this.$data).forEach(key => this.$data[key] = null);
       // set all properties from newdata into data
       Object.entries(newdata).forEach(entry => Vue.set(this.$data, entry[0], entry[1]));
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>Name: {{ name }}</p>
  <p>Age: {{ age }}</p>
  <button @click="changeWholeData">Change Whole Data</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure! Btw, may I ask why you chose the other? (Just curiosity, really, the other is a great solution as well, you should keep it as accepted!)

Comment: I'm a newbie of using Vue, and I was a coder using Microsoft ASP.NET, in ASP.NET, it's easy to set element.DataSource=somedata, so I thought Vue should be in the same way, now I know I was wrong. Thank you, you are so kind.

Comment: @Jinmin You were only wrong if you want to be wrong. You can easily add a `dataSource` property to your data object to wrap the data you want to swap out. Use this to create your Vue root: `var data = { dataSource: originalData };` then you can replace it like this `vueobj.dataSource = newdata;`

Answer (score 2):

As it says, you need to use a nested property to wrap the data you want to replace so it just takes a little planning up front.

If you create your Vue instance like this,

```
var vueobj = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dataSource: {
        name: 'Alice',
        age: 30
    }
  }
})
```

then you can replace your data like this

```
vueobj.dataSource = newdata;
```

The `dataSource` wrapper property can be any valid property name. The downside is you can no longer access your inner properties directly on the `Vue` instance. E.G. you have to use `vueobj.dataSource.name` instead of `vueobj.name`, but I guess that's the trade off for all the other ease of use Vue is providing. You could create a `name` computed to solve this on a case-by-case basis but it would  be tedious to do if there are many root properties.